# How do I changes a USB drive letter without the Disk Management snap-in

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, hard-drive, drive-letter

I've got a user who wants to be able change the dive letter a USB drive is being assigned. Naturally, I'd use the Disk Management snap-in. However, my user doesn't have sufficient privileges to run it (and as policy, I can't give that to them).

I also cannot install USBDLM for them.

Is there another way for them change the drive letter on a USB drive; native to windows?

Comment: the registry where it is stored at. If they did not have privilege to run the disk manager then editing the registry is not going to happen right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drive letters can be reassigned using `mountvol` or `diskpart`.

However, neither of them will work if the account simply lacks permissions to write to the required part of registry.