# Is there a way to change a drive letter directly in explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Normally this is done through disk management, but it seems like there should be a way to do it directly in windows explorer.  This could be useful if you are working with a lot of flash or external drives.

While I realize there is no native solution, I was hoping there might be an easy way to do this directly in the windows explorer interface.  I thought maybe somebody else had written a tool or maybe an autohotkey script or some other type of script.

Comment: Is it really that important to have drive letters to your liking if you don't have to type them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I changes a USB drive letter without the Disk Management snap-in](http://superuser.com/questions/379546/how-do-i-changes-a-usb-drive-letter-without-the-disk-management-snap-in)

Comment: I am organizing historic backups on external drives and I would like to be able to assign a specific letter to the temporary drive, the source drive, and the destination drive so they are easier to track.  I will be switching these out quite often and sometimes the source drive will then become the destination drive and assigning specific drive letters will help prevent copying the wrong files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script.

Note that AutoHotkey must be running as administrator for this work.

To use this, select the drive in Windows Explorer like so:

[image: Explorer Drive Selection]

And then press ALT+L.

This will load up diskpart with the volume selected and will wait for you to enter a new drive letter:

[image: DiskPart]

Now just type in the new drive letter and press Enter.

The script does not perform any sort of error detection so use at your own risk.
This script does not detect mapped network drives and will attempt to change them as if they were local drives.
Furthermore, there is no way to cancel the script once it has started.  To cancel it, just press Escape followed by Enter.

You could, in fact, select any file on the target volume and it would still work.

Here is the script:

```
; Retrieved from
; http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/100983-how-can-we-retrieve-the-name-of-a-file-selected/
Explorer_GetSelection(hwnd="")
{
  hwnd := hwnd ? hwnd : WinExist("A")
  WinGetClass class, ahk_id %hwnd%
  if (class="CabinetWClass" or class="ExploreWClass" or class="Progman")
    for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
      if (window.hwnd==hwnd)
        sel := window.Document.SelectedItems
        for item in sel
        ToReturn .= item.path "`n"
        return Trim(ToReturn,"`n")
}

#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
!l::
currentLetter:=SubStr(Explorer_GetSelection(), 1, 1)
if RegExMatch(currentLetter, "i)[a-z]") == 0
  Return
Run, diskpart
Sleep 2000 ; Wait 2 seconds
Send, SELECT VOLUME %currentLetter%{enter}
Sleep 2500
Send, REM Please enter the new drive letter and press Enter{enter}
Send, ASSIGN LETTER=
Input, newDriveLetter, I V, {enter}
Send, {enter}
Send, EXIT{enter}
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Windows Explorer.

You could do it through the command line using [`diskpart`](http://www.howtogeek.com/197296/how-to-use-the-diskpart-utility-to-assign-and-remove-drive-letters/).